# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).unmask is not a function(…)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, maskedinput

I have a method in an JS file. am submitting a method using a unmask but It says unmask error. Why I do not know please help me with it.

maskedinput version:

```
  <script src="resources/js/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>
```

Code :

```
$("#btn").submit(function() {
  $("#txtPhone").unmask();
});
```

Comment: is txtPhone element on DOM ?

Comment: i do not know what you mean?

Comment: you're using element with ID txtPhone is that element on HTML DOM ?

Comment: Also check does your `unmask library` loaded correctly

Comment: @VinodLouis: i am new to this. please give me some sample code.

Comment: you must include jquery.min.js

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/igorescobar/6pco4om7/